# How can I array aggregate per column where distinct values are less than a given number in Google BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, aggregate, analytics

I have a dataset table like this in Google Big Query:

```
| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 |
-------------------------------------------
|  a1  |  b1  |  c1  |  d1  |  e2  |  f1  |
|  a2  |  b2  |  c2  |  d1  |  e2  |  f2  |
|  a1  |  b3  |  c3  |  d1  |  e3  |  f2  |
|  a2  |  b1  |  c4  |  d1  |  e4  |  f2  |
|  a1  |  b2  |  c5  |  d1  |  e5  |  f2  |
```

Let's say the given threshold number is 4, in that case, I want to transform this into one of the tables given below:

```
|     col1     |    col2    |    col4    |    col5     |    col6    |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|    [a1,a2]   |  [b1,b2,b] |    [d1]    |[e2,e3,e4,e5]|   [f1,f2]  |
```

Or like this:

```
| col  | values        |
------------------------
| col1 | [a1,a2]       |
| col2 | [b1,b2,b]     |
| col4 | [d1]          |
| col5 | [e2,e3,e4,e5] |
| col6 | [f1,f2]       |
```

Please note col3 was removed because it contained more than 4 (threshold) distinct values. I explored lot of documents [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_analytic_functions) but was not able to figure out the required query. Can somebody help or point in the right direction ?

Edit: I have one solution in mind, where I do something like this:

```
select * from (select 'col1', array_aggregate(distinct col1) as values union all
select 'col2', array_aggregate(distinct col2) as values union all
select 'col3', array_aggregate(distinct col3) as values union all
select 'col4', array_aggregate(distinct col4) as values union all
select 'col5', array_aggregate(distinct col5) as values) X where array_length(values) > 4;
```

This will give me the second result but requires complex query construction assuming I don't know the number and names of the columns up front. Also, this might cross 100MB per row limit for BigQuery table as I will be having more than a billion rows in the table. Please also suggest if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: do you need col3 to be removed on the first example? or would it being empty be enough?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I can think of some workaround for my use-case if I get col3 empty with other columns. So yeah that should work, please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```sql
WITH arrays AS (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST((
    SELECT [
      STRUCT("col_repo_name" AS col, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT repo.name IGNORE NULLS LIMIT 1001) AS values)
      , ('col_actor_login', ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT actor.login IGNORE NULLS LIMIT 1001))
      , ('col_type', ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT type IGNORE NULLS LIMIT 1001))
      , ('col_org_login', ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT org.login IGNORE NULLS LIMIT 1001))
      ]
    FROM `githubarchive.year.2017` 
  ))
)

SELECT *
FROM arrays
WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH(values)<=1000
```

This query processed 20.6GB in 11.9s (half billion rows). It only returned one row, because every other row had more than 1000 unique values (my threshold).

[image]

That's traditional SQL -- but see here an even simpler query, that produces similar results:

```sql
SELECT col, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT value IGNORE NULLS LIMIT 1001) values
FROM (
  SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(x, r'"([^\"]*)"') col , REGEXP_EXTRACT(x, r'":"([^\"]*)"') value
  FROM (
    SELECT SPLIT(TO_JSON_STRING(STRUCT(repo.name, actor.login, type, org.login)), ',') x
    FROM `githubarchive.year.2017`
  ), UNNEST(x) x
)
GROUP BY col
HAVING ARRAY_LENGTH(values)<=1000

# 17.0 sec elapsed, 20.6 GB processed
```

Caveat: This will only run if there are no special values in the columns, like quotes or commas. If you have those, it won't be as straightforward (but still possible).

Comment: Thanks a lot! @FelipeHoffa Although I won't be able to use the second query as I am expecting special characters to be there but first one will still serve my purpose thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT col, STRING_AGG(DISTINCT value) `values`
FROM (
  SELECT 
    TRIM(z[OFFSET(0)], '"') col,
    TRIM(z[OFFSET(1)], '"') value
  FROM `project.dataset.table` t,
  UNNEST(SPLIT(TRIM(to_JSON_STRING(t), '{}'))) kv,
  UNNEST([STRUCT(SPLIT(kv, ':') AS z)])
)
GROUP BY col 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT value) < 5
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question - result will be

```
Row col     values   
1   col1    a1,a2    
2   col2    b1,b2,b3     
3   col4    d1   
4   col5    e2,e3,e4,e5  
5   col6    f1,f2
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I might have special characters in my input data so that splitting will not work for my use case :)

Answer (score 0):

@FelipeHoffa I was able to use your idea with a little modification in the query for my use-case.

```
SELECT * FROM UNNEST((
    SELECT [
      STRUCT("col_repo_name" AS col, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT repo.name IGNORE NULLS LIMIT 1001) AS values)
      , ('col_actor_login', ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT actor.login IGNORE NULLS LIMIT 1001))
      , ('col_type', ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT type IGNORE NULLS LIMIT 1001))
      , ('col_org_login', ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT org.login IGNORE NULLS LIMIT 1001))
      ]
    FROM `githubarchive.year.2017` 
  ))
```

This UNNEST on an array of structs will not work as it is because the underlying columns will have different data-types and BigQuery will not be able to put the arrays under a single column (with error like this: **Array elements of types {STRUCT>, STRUCT>} do not have a common supertype**). I modified it to something like this to serve my use-case.

```
SELECT * FROM UNNEST((
    SELECT [
      STRUCT("col_repo_name" AS col, to_json_string(ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT repo.name IGNORE NULLS LIMIT 1001)) AS values)
      , ('col_actor_login', to_json_string(ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT actor.login IGNORE NULLS LIMIT 1001)))
      , ('col_type', to_json_string(ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT type IGNORE NULLS LIMIT 1001)))
      , ('col_org_login', to_json_string(ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT org.login IGNORE NULLS LIMIT 1001)))
      ]
    FROM `githubarchive.year.2017` 
  ))
```

And this worked well !